# how to fetch previous values of a table in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

[image]

1. My first task is to add two new columns to a table, first column stores the values of M and X fields values in a single column(as a single unit with a pipe separator) and second column stores O and Z fields values in a single column(as a single unit with a pipe separator).
2. second task selecting agency and external letter rating(shown in image) from drop down and after saving the form the value from fields M and X should move to N and Y and this values should be stored in table column that are created from task one, Now if we save the form the values should move to O and Z fields in forms and this should continue.

Can any one help me how to proceed with this and I don't know how to separate a column value into pieces and display on form.

Better if you propose any new  method that does the same work.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding columns:**

That's a bad idea. Concatenating values is easy; storing them into a column as well. But, then - in the next step - you have to **split** those values into two values (columns? rows?) to be joined to another value and produce result. Can you do it? Sure. Should you? No.

What to do? If you want to store 4 values, then add 4 columns to a table.

Alternatively, see if you can create a master-detail relationship between **two tables** so you'd actually create a new table (with a foreign key to existing table) with two additional columns:

- one that says is value stored related to M or Y
- value itself

It looks like more job to do, but - should pay off in the future.

**Layout:**

That really looks like a tabular form, which only supports what I previously said. You can't "dynamically" add rows (or, even if you could, that's really something you should avoid because you'd have to add (actually, *display*) separate **items** (not rows that share the same item name).