# how to populate previously saved values in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

[image]

In the above pic agency field is a drop down with some values, if I select one value and save the form and close it. now  if i open the form the value selected previously should appear in the second row(field) and if again if i select new value in drop down and save it, the value in first should move to second and and previous value from second row should move to third. there are three columns c1, c2, c3 for each field in table.
the above is my reqirement.  To achieve this how should i proceed.

Answer (score 0):

That's similar to one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71828048/how-to-fetch-previous-values-of-a-table-in-oracle-forms). Just like then, I still think that what you want to do is wrong. That's not how Forms *natively* work.

If you want to do that, it means that **none** of those 3 fields is a database field. Moreover, it means that you can't use built-in capabilities of data manipulation - you'll have to write your own code to insert / update / select values.

- Can you do it? Sure, by writing your own triggers.
- Should you do it? I believe not.

Comment: they are database columns

Comment: Nope (if you want to do what you described). They should be *control fields* (not related to database columns) and your own code should be responsible for all DML you'll be doing.